# How to change a color of the tabs Indicator text in TabWidget in android?

Tags: android, xml, customization, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I have a really big problem.
I'm trying to do a simple application. I'm using tabs there, and I really don't know how to change text color in tabWidget dynamically.

How can I change my xml's or java code for text to change dynamically?

That's what I have in java code:

TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

```
    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("creator");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.Card);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Debit Card");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("account");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.Account);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Checking Account");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

and that's my xml files:

background selector - tab_bg.xml:

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected"></item>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected"></item>
<item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected"></item>

<item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected"></item>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected"></item>
<item android:state_active="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected"></item>
```

tab_bg_selected.xml:

```
   android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/white"/>

<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
         android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
         android:topRightRadius="5dp"
         android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
<stroke android:color="@color/blue"
        android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

and tab_bg_unselected.xml:

```
   android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/blue"/>

<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
         android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
         android:topRightRadius="5dp"
         android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>

<stroke android:color="@color/blue"
        android:width="2dp"/>
```